# Lower core web vitals esp. TTI and TBT

Tags: next.js, compilation, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

I have an application, based on nextjs and styled with bootstrap and boosted with CMS as Contentful. As altough i think an optimized component code and well structured codebase i have, even so **i have too high (according to lighthouse report and my sigths) values like TBT: ^900ms,~ and TTI: ^5s~ and i am giving error and suggestions about decreasing this, but none of them worked for me.** 
 My code is using imports dynamic and optimizes images with  tag. **I giving also error, Minimize main thread work, Decrease javascript execution time** As a question for need help as mainly, **IS THIS ISSUE ABOUT NEXTJS CORE, OR MY CODEBASE OR LIGHTHOUSE REPORT STABILTY ISSUES** Please help me for further, because i am newbie about at this environment but i want to develop faster and optimized web apps. Here is the section of my code and lighthouse reports belong that.

Build info:

```
Page                                       Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      325 B          86.3 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B            85.9 kB
├ ○ /404                                   186 B          86.1 kB
├ ● /fav                                   979 B          90.9 kB
├   └ css/bb088f67d088528d.css             177 B
├ ● /kisiler                               12 kB          97.9 kB
├   └ css/be220b594c062efc.css             289 B
└ ● /son                                   923 B          90.8 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              85.9 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-9b5d6ec4444c80fa.js   45.7 kB
  ├ chunks/main-a48e19342d61e886.js        31.5 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-15744340ea12860c.js  6.23 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack-b6c83210d4a4e3ee.js     2.52 kB
  └ css/462846736ad77231.css               39.4 kB
```

_app.tsx file:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

import Head from "next/head";

import Layout from "../components/layout/Layout";

import "../styles/globals.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.svg" type="image/x-icon" />
        <title>Dialer</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Dialer app" />
      </Head>

      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

pages/son/index.tsx:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import Link from "next/link";

import { Suspense } from "react";

import Spinner from "react-bootstrap/Spinner";

import { client } from "../../cms/setup";

import type { C, SonProps } from "../../types/types";

const DKisiKayit = dynamic(() => import("../../components/kisiler/KisiKayit"));
const DSearch = dynamic(() => import("../../components/layout/Search"));

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res: C = await client.getEntries({
    order: "-sys.updatedAt",
    content_type: "kisi",
    "fields.iscalled": true,
  });

  return { props: { kisiler: res.items }, revalidate: 60 };
};

const Son = ({ kisiler }: SonProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      {kisiler.length === 0 ? (
        <div>
          // here is a svg which not important just icon
          <p>Hiç kayıt yok, eklemek için birilerini arayın</p>
          <Link href="/kisiler">
            <a>Kişiler</a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Suspense fallback={<Spinner animation="border" />}>
          <DSearch kisiler={kisiler} />
          {/* arama kaydı kartı */}
          <DKisiKayit kisiler={kisiler} />
        </Suspense>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Son;
```

Lighthouse report: (at 6x slowdown, slow 3G, mobile)

[report ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcHYT.png)

Comment: Are you using the app in production mode (`next build && next start`) when running the Lighthouse test? Can you show us the code for the `/son` page and `_app` file?

Comment: here is the updated question, please check that out maybe it helps. @juliomalves